# Sorting a tensor list in ascending order

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I am working on a facial comparison app that will give me the closest n number of faces to my target face.

I have done this with dlib/face_recognition as it uses numpy arrays, however i am now trying to do the same thing with facenet/pytorch and running into an issue because it uses tensors.

I have created a database of embeddings and I am giving the function one picture to compare to them. What i would like is for it to sort the list from lowest distances to highest, and give me the lowest 5 results or so.

here is the code I am working on that is doing the comparison. at this point i am feeding it a photo and asking it to compare against the embedding database.

```
def face_match(img_path, data_path): # img_path= location of photo, data_path= location of data.pt 
    # getting embedding matrix of the given img
    img_path = (os.getcwd()+'/1.jpg')
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    face = mtcnn(img) # returns cropped face and probability
    emb = resnet(face.unsqueeze(0)).detach() # detech is to make required gradient false

    saved_data = torch.load('data.pt') # loading data.pt file
    embedding_list = saved_data[0] # getting embedding data
    name_list = saved_data[1] # getting list of names
    dist_list = [] # list of matched distances, minimum distance is used to identify the person
    
    for idx, emb_db in enumerate(embedding_list):
        dist = torch.dist(emb, emb_db)
        dist_list.append(dist)
    
    namestodistance = list(zip(name_list,dist_list))
    
    print(namestodistance)

face_match('1.jpg', 'data.pt')
```

This results in giving me all the names and their distance from the target photo in alphabetical order of the names, in the form of `(Adam Smith, tensor(1.2123432))`, Brian Smith, `tensor(0.6545464)` etc. If the 'tensor' wasn't part of every entry I think it would be no problem to sort it. I don't quite understand why its being appended to the entries. I can cut this down to the best 5 by adding `[0:5]` at the end of dist_list, but I can't figure out how to sort the list, I think the problem is the word tensor being in every entry.

I have tried
`for idx, emb_db in enumerate(embedding_list): dist = torch.dist(emb, emb_db) sorteddist = torch.sort(dist)`
but for whatever reason this only returns one distance value, and it isn't the smallest one.

`idx_min = dist_list.index(min(dist_list))`, this works fine in giving me the lowest value and then matching it to a name using `namelist[idx_min]`, therefore giving the best match, but I would like the best 5 matches in order as opposed to just the best match.

Anyone able to solve this ?

Comment: I believe you want to do this in Pytorch, if so, please remove TensorFlow tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot test your code, but to me it seems like you are operation on a python list of tuples. You can sort that by using a key:

```
namestodistance = [('Alice', .1), ('Bob', .3), ('Carrie', .2)]
names_top = sorted(namestodistance, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(names_top[:2])
```

Of course you have to modify the anonymous function in `key` to return a sortable value instead of e.g. a `torch.tensor`.

This can be done by using `key = lambda x: x[1].item()`.

Edit: To answer the question that crept up in the comments, we can refactor our code a little. Namely

```
namestodistance = list(map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1].item()), namestodistance)
names_top = sorted(namestodistance, key=lambda x: x[1])
print(names_top[:2])
```

Comment: This works in sorting it but I displays my results like this [('Adam, Smith', tensor(0.8701)), ('Brian, Smith', tensor(1.0608))]. Is there way to get rid of the 'tensor' from that?

Comment: I tried top_hits = (names_top[:2] followed by rmtensor = top_hits.remove('tensor'), to remove that word from the list but getting this error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: If I try using key = lambda x: x[1][0], i get this error: names_top = sorted(bestmatches, key=lambda x: x[1][0])
IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use `tensor.item()` in Python or `tensor.item<T>()` in C++ to convert a 0-dim tensor to a number

Comment: Edited my answer, but since I solved you original question please mar as answered. Even if the edit doesn't work.

Comment: Also if you keep getting this error, try following the error message and replace `x[0][1]` by `x[0].item()`. Again I cannot test your code, since I don't have an example. If you want further help please make one.

Comment: Yes you did, I will mark it answered. Do you know of a way to get rid of the word tensor though? Implementing the updated code you added gives this error IndexError: invalid index of a 0-dim tensor. Use `tensor.item()` in Python or `tensor.item<T>()` in C++ to convert a 0-dim tensor to a number

Comment: The error message is literally telling you how to fix it. Please update my awnser wit the correct solution once it works.

Comment: Thanks Alex, Ill work on it a bit longer and if I still cant figure it out ill make a new question. I know its telling me how to fix it, but adding that fix breaks your sorting method.     names_top = sorted(bestmatches, key=lambda x: x[1][0])
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Change  `x[1][0]` to `x[1]`.

Comment: Ok. Everything works now. Not sure I understand why it works but it works. Thanks again Alex

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239867/discussion-between-alexne-and-cfive).